# How do we set a header, footer to a popup screen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I need to have the header and footer in Red color. and the body must be a transparent color. When my application UI is shown, I need to make sure the body of the screen is transparent color.. and I must be able to see other applications behind. it must not be a solid color.

Answer (score 1):

A header and a footer exists for MainScreen not for popupScreen. You can have your custom managers that will do the job for you or simply use the MainScreen api